# How do I save ftp.plist file when using sudo nano?

Tags: ftp, sudo

I edited ftp.plist by using sudo nano in terminal, and I saved by control + O but after reboot, it changed again. How can I save the file?

Comment: We are talking about /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/ftp.plist I assume. Did you verify whether your changes were written to the file after leaving nano?

Comment: Do you not want the file to be modified once you edit it?

Comment: It was written well. Because when I quit terminal and open the file again, it was changed. But after rebooting, it changed like before it is edited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Finder navigate to /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/ftp.plist

1. File > Get info <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>i</kbd>
2. Tick the "Locked" box

The file should not change now when you reboot.

[image: Locked]

Comment: I cannot see the file in the directory like this. http://imgur.com/CsgPm So I edited the file using Terminal. Is there any option for see all files?

Comment: I solved this problem by changing built-in ftp server's port to 9221 in etc/services file.